# How to add methods to has_many relationship on runtime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to add belatedly methods to has_many relationships, and I don't want to do it neither in build time (:has_many panties do ... end ) nor I want to do it for a certain scope (I want it to work in every has_many, or for that matter, collection association). I already tried:

1. Including methods in the ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionAssociation class
2. Including methods in the ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy class

nothing seemed to work. I could only track that non-defined methods would be passed to the class, and that's just not what I want.

My desired result would be this:

```
class Man < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :balls
end

class Woman < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :breasts
end

# magic to insert methods

Man.new.balls.say_hi #=> "hi jerry"
Woman.new.breasts.say_hi #=> "hi jerry"
```

So simple, yet so difficult. This proxying of methods in AR makes it so difficult to debug.

Edit:

My purpose is not to insert more business logic, but add composition to the collections, in order for me to extract information about the collection and use it somewhere else. This information, I repeat, doesn't have to do with the business logic, but with some activerecord information which is "hidden" inside the collection association, like knowing which class are the children, name of association in parent, and so on.

This composite object would then be available through a collection method like #composite_object, which would provide me with this information. But I don't know how to insert this method without redefining the association a second time.

Comment: This question doesn't make a lot of sense, if you want to perform a method on a collection of childen the proper place is in the parent. Your examples don't help explain the scenario you are trying to solve. Also, it's a bit vulgar.

Comment: I don't want to act on the children exactly, but on the collection itself. I want to use composition to extend the composition and extract certain information from it to be used in a subsequent module.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered ActiveRecord::QueryMethods#extending method? http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/extending

```rb
module Belatedly
  def say_hi
    "hi jerry"
  end
end

children = Child.all.extending Belatedly
children.say_hi

class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :children, -> { extending Belatedly }
end

Parent.first.children.say_hi
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define an around alias for [has_many](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_many) which resides in `ActiveRecord::Associations::ClassMethods` through an open module.

That around alias would simply call the old `has_many` method and then use `define_method` to add `say_hi`.

Comment: my purpose is not to alias_method_chain activerecord more than it is already, but cleanly inserting methods in an associated collection cleanly. This would be for a gem, and if all gems start aliasing has_many for their own purposes, something will explode eventually.$